# Add rows to pandas to complete sequence

Tags: python, pandas

What's the best way of completing a pandas dataframe like so:

```
order |  group | value
 -3   |   a    |  0
 -2   |   a    |  3
 -4   |   b    |  2
```

I want to automatically add null rows such that the order column ends at 0, split by group values (doesn't have to be in order, just need the rows to exist)

```
order |  group | value
 -3   |   a    |  0
 -2   |   a    |  3
 -1   |   a    |  nan
  0   |   a    |  nan
 -4   |   b    |  2
 -3   |   b    |  nan
 -2   |   b    |  nan
 -1   |   b    |  nan
  0   |   b    |  nan
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `groupby` then `reindex`

```
df.groupby('group').\
   apply(lambda x : x.set_index('order').reindex(-np.arange(max(x['order'].abs()+1)))).\
      drop('group',1).reset_index()
Out[135]: 
  group  order  value
0     a      0    NaN
1     a     -1    NaN
2     a     -2    3.0
3     a     -3    0.0
4     b      0    NaN
5     b     -1    NaN
6     b     -2    NaN
7     b     -3    NaN
8     b     -4    2.0
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you be able to explain what's going on?

Comment: @NBC we just group by group , then reindex for each subset, set the order as in dex , and create the index for each group by using their min value (which is abs max value)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list comprehension` and `reindex`

```
dfs = [df[df['group'] == g] for g in df.group.unique()]
df_f = pd.concat([a.set_index('order').reindex(range(a.iloc[0].order, 1)) for a in dfs])
df_f['group'] = df_f.group.ffill()

        group   value
order       
-3      a       0.0
-2      a       3.0
-1      a       NaN
0       a       NaN
-4      b       2.0
-3      b       NaN
-2      b       NaN
-1      b       NaN
0       b       NaN
```